# WHERE conditions being listed in a column if they are met

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a file that i receive each morning which contains details of customers whos information doesnt meet certain criteria, i have built a script with many WHERE conditions that, if met, will show customers information and put them in a file but im having trouble finding out ***why*** they are wrong.

As i have many conditions in the where clause, is there a way to show which column has the incorrect information

For example i could have a table like this:

```
NAME|ADDRESS   |PHONE|COUNTRY
John|123avenue |12345|UK
```

My conditions could be

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE NAME LIKE 'J%' 
AND LEFT(PHONE,1) = '1'
```

so it would show in the file as two conditions are met, but as i have over 80 rows and 40 conditions, its hard to look at each row and find out why its in their.

Is there a way i can add a column which will tell me which WHERE condition has been met?

Comment: Tag which DBMS(SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc ... ) are you using.

Comment: @Valerica updated

Comment: Oracle doesn't use TSQL, it uses PL/SQL

Comment: @MatBailie I would like to know for BOTH TSQL and Oracle

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `left()` so I assume this is SQL Server.

Comment: Since it is an AND then all conditions matched

Answer (score 2):

As worded, no.  You should reverse your logic.  Add fields that show what's wrong, then use those fields in a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN LEFT(phone, 1) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS phone_starts_with_1,
  CASE WHEN LEFT(name,  1) = 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS name_starts_with_z
FROM
  customers
WHERE
     phone_starts_with_1 = 1
  OR name_starts_with_z = 1
```

Depending on which dialect of SQL you use, you may need to nest this, such that the new fields are resolved before you can use them in the WHERE clause...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(phone, 1) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS phone_starts_with_1,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(name,  1) = 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS name_starts_with_z
  FROM
    customers
)
  checks
WHERE
     phone_starts_with_1 = 1
  OR name_starts_with_z = 1
```

Comment: If it's Oracle, you would need to select `customer.*, ...` as it will error with an unprefixed `*, <anything>`. But then `left()` won't work either, of course...

Comment: Agreed.  I'll leave it as an exercise for the OP ;)